# pkgadd prototype file that doesn't break links

Tags: prototype, solaris, packaging, hyperlink

How can I create a solaris package that will not to break soft links when the package gets installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class field in the prototype file to conditionally install things. For example:

```
d none /foo 0775 $USER $GROUP
d createbar /bar 0775 $USER $GROUP
```

The directory /foo will normally always be created because "none" is the default class. On the other hand, /bar will only be created if the installer is set to install things in the "createbar" class.

The initial set of classes to install is set in the `pkginfo` file. You can alter the class list in the `request` or `checkinstall` scripts. The idea is for one of these scripts to perform some check to decide whether to install the optional components, then alter CLASSES appropriately. For example:

```
# Create /bar unless it already exists as a symlink
if [ ! -L /bar ]
then
    echo "CLASSES=${CLASSES} createbar"
fi
```

If this answer doesn't meet your needs, maybe you could give a better description of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are these symbolic links parts of your package prototype file ?
If so, how are they defined ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons Not a new question, This should have been a comment to the OP question. A four years old mistake. Will remove it shortly

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by breaking links? I can think of a couple of things that might happen to the links:

1. Overwrite a symlink with a file
2. Overwrite a symlink with a directory
3. Put a file into a directory to which a symlink is pointing (say, you install into /opt/foo/bar, and /opt/foo is a symlink)

It would help if you clarified your question.

In either case however, the [class action scripts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-0406/ch3enhancepkg-10289.html#ch3enhancepkg-37319) are something you might want to look at, if you want to handle certain files from your package in a special way.

In the prototype file, you need to assign a class name to a file, and in a different package, you need to provide a script which will handle this class.  You can take a look at [CSWcswclassutils](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWcswclassutils), a package which provides a number of class action examples. You would create a similar package providing a class action script, and use the scripts in your package with special files.